# Why do i get different timestamps for the same date in ruby and javascripts

Tags: jquery, ruby

i am confused as to why i get different timestamps for the same date in ruby and javascript.

**In ruby**

```
> ruby_date = Date.new(2012,1,1)
> ruby_date.to_time.utc.to_i
 => 1325368800
```

**In jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var jquery_date = Date.UTC(2012,1,1);
    document.write(jquery_date);

</script>
```

returns 1328054400000.

Why is there a difference in timestamps. Please explain. I am looking for the number of seconds from epoch. thank you

Comment: What in `Date.UTC` makes you think that it's jQuery? (It's ECMAScript btw)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, Sorry for that, its been a long day fighting with my pc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20806052/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not pass a time value to the date object. Both implementations are assuming a different time of the specified day:

```
1325368800 = 31.12.2011 22:00:00


1328054400 = 01.02.2012 00:00:00
```

Note, that i removed the last 3 digits of the Javascript timestamp because they are stored in milliseconds (thanks rjz).

Mark Rushakoff explained the month gap in his answer.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that Javascript timestamps are counted in milliseconds (1000x larger than a standard unix timestamp).

Comment: @Alp thanks a lot, saved me a couple of hours of head banging, i owe you guys a beer. I did not realize that i left out the time value.

Comment: Glad i could help. Send the beer to Germany please, could need one right now :)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is (most likely) because the month in Javascript's [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) is zero-based and the Ruby's [`Date.now`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new) is one-based.