# Why is there an about 30 days missing in JS Date Difference Script

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JavaScript and Jquery and I came across a solution to subtract 2 dates from each other. However, the result is short of 30 days. How come? What am I doing incorrectly? Also, what would be best practice?

```
<script>
    var d1 = new Date(); // todays date
    var d2 = new Date(2011,12,27);
    var msPerDay = 1000*60*60*24;
    document.write( ((d1 - d2) / msPerDay).toFixed(0) + " days");
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: because months start at 0 in js

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax : *"month: Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December."*

Comment: On an unrelated note, I suggest using `console.log` for debugging instead of `document.write`. You can access your console via ctrl+shift+J or via the F12 developer tools. If you debug via the console, it's much easier seeing what you actually need, and you can even inject javascript right there without needing to save any files.

Comment: If you can, use moment.js it abstracts a lot of this logic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Javascript months are zero-based.

December is `11`.
`12` will wrap around and become January of the next year.

Comment: Thank you, This explains a lot! Would this also be the case for days?